# The Nadam optimizer does not support tf.keras.optimizers.LearningRateSchedules as the learning rate

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, learning-rate

this is my first question here. I'm playing with tensorflow.keras, doing some CNNs, and I would like to know if anyone understands why this conflict arises, thanks.

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Nadam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules import ExponentialDecay 

initial_learning_rate = 0.1
lr_schedule = ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate,
    decay_steps=100000, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True)


model.compile(optimizer=Nadam(learning_rate=lr_schedule), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the conflict?. I am also learning to use keras.optimizers.schedules. I'm thinking of doing a gridsearch,but i still have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This `ValueError: The Nadam optimizer does not support tf.keras.optimizers.LearningRateSchedules as the learning rate` is caused because [Nadam](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Nadam) optimzer does not support LearningRateSchedule as other optimzers do.

You can use other [optimizers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers) except `Nadam` which supports schedules.

- Adadelta
- Adagrad
- Adam
- Adamx
- Ftrl
- RMSprop
- SGD